# TinyMCE would not load in firefox

Tags: firefox, tinymce, wysiwyg

Below is my script to load tinymce.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        tinyMCE.init({
            mode: "textareas",
            theme: "advanced",
            plugins : "code,table",

            // Theme options - button# indicated the row# only
            theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,bullist,numlist,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,tablecontrols,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,sub,sup,|,code",
            theme_advanced_buttons2: "",
            theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
            theme_advanced_font_sizes: "12px,13px,14px,16px,18px,20px",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
            theme_advanced_resizing: true
        });
</script>
```

It wouldn't work in Firefox but works in IE. 
In IE > Developer Tools, I see this link in head section

```
<link href="http://www.xyz.com/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/skins/default/ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

But in Firefox, with Firebug > NET > I see a 404 error (red line) at

```
http://www.xyz.com/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/code/editor_plugin.js
```

I did not find **code** folder under tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/ folder.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no code folder under the plugins directory, then remove it from the list of plugins:

```
plugins : "table",
```

or find the missing code plugin.

Comment: Thank you so much Ross. I chose the 2nd option :)   Plugins folder had **bbcode**. I copied contents of that folder into **code** folder and its working great now! Thanks again for pointing me in right direction.

Comment: But still wondering how its working in IE but not in FF with the code folder missing!